# Complex Transform of Image file in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, graphics

I have a project in C# where we take multiple fixed sized images and generate a composite image.  The fixed sized images require some distortion which is not simple skewing.  So from a perfectly square image, I need to do this:

[image: Sample]

I've been able to do a simple skew (moving the corners) but this request is more complex (the bottom half increasingly bends outwards) and I don't quite know where to start.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  We may need to hire someone for this project but I need to know what skills to target.

Comment: whoever requests this of you needs to provide a mathematical description, or explain this thumbnail of an illustration. better yet, find our who _they_ got their marching orders from. they're likely a messenger who doesn't understand the goal. -- from looking in my crystal ball I'd say you need someone who understands computer graphics. you might have to overlay a mesh and apply the source data as a texture, then deform the mesh (or the other way around).

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Trust me, we understand the goal and this distortion requirement was not arrived at lightly.  It's unsavory but it is required.  The graphic artist has manipulated the images manually to achieve the proper amount of distortion so it will require some trial and error to mimic it mathematically.  So you're thinking some sort of 2D mesh manipulation.  Maybe someone that does graphics programming for games?

Comment: perhaps. depends on the rest of the code around it. textured polygons are versatile. if you don't go that route, you'd at least need someone who is aware of the concepts, knows the linear algebra behind everything, and isn't insane enough to reimplement it all from scratch.

Comment: if this effect is *defined* by things a graphic artist does with a photo editor, I'd recommend having them do that to some pictures of linear gradients (one vertical one horizontal). assuming the effect doesn't change values, only positions, now you could extract a per-pixel mapping for whatever they did in their graphics program... `cv::remap` and stuff

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz This sound intriguing but I don't understand it.  Can you elaborate or provide an example?  I attempted to reach out directly but I didn't see any contact info in your profile.

Comment: that's basically a lookup table. -- get them to make RGB-linear gray gradients, one horizontal, one vertical, and then have them warp each. present all those pictures.

Comment: Something like this?  https://ibb.co/tC7tTK3

Comment: yes, except the input has to be straight and rectangular (and preferably gray, but there are complicated patterns that give more resolution), and the output, from the operations of the graphic artist, has whatever shape, and "carries" these deformations. -- in fact, you should use these https://imgur.com/a/MKPJGj4

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but I don't get what you're saying I should do with the gradients.  Do I need to skew them on a different background?  Or is it more of a morphing of the gradient itself?  I'm still not clear on the requirements.  I thought I could take the gradients, skew them and place them on a different background (e.g. any color not in the gradient), but I don't think that's what you're describing.

I want to hire a contractor to do this but I can't explain it myself so it makes it difficult.

Comment: I'm not gonna gnaw through (international) law and tax code. that's worse than eternal damnation. -- consider the gray gradients. pick any pixel. its *value* encodes its *position* (x or y). -- now go back to your graphic, the blue square and red circle. the graphic artist warped/deformed that, right? -- now, instead of deforming that square n circle, have them deform that gradient, exactly the same. -- NOW, in the artist's output, pick a pixel, any pixel. its *value* will encode the position it *came from*. make sense? -- the colorful variants are just fancier (higher resolution).

Comment: We use international consulting agencies (big company) but it seems my best option now is to look for a Python programmer with OpenCV experience.  The skewing required can be mathematically defined, actually.  I just don't know how to do those calculations.  To get more specific would require an NDA.  Anyway, thanks so much for the bread crumbs.  I at least feel like I have a path to research.